# Creating a view without using subquerys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-view

I'm working on a project that contains a mysql database.

I want to create a view that makes queries much easier. But I got a problem. Since the tables that are used in the view contains each about 100.000 rows and I'm joining four of them, the view has to use the **merge** algorithm. But according to the [MySQL documentaion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html):

> **MERGE** *cannot* be used if the view contains any of the following
> constructs:
>
> - Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
> - DISTINCT
> - GROUP BY
> - HAVING
> - LIMIT
> - UNION or UNION ALL
> - Subquery in the select list
> - Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table)

So how I would insert an lookup, if something already exists

```
EXIST( SELECT id FROM table WHERE col > val) AS flag
```

or the latest id belonging to an other id

```
(SELECT id FROM payments WHER contract_id = val ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_payment_id
```

into a view, without using a subquery? At the moment I try to avoid this. In some cases I could add a valid period of the rows (DATE valid_from, DATE valid_to) such that al periods are distinct for each contract_id, so it is unique and so I need no sorting or limiting. But this is realy ugly.

Is there a recommended way of doing such subqueries without a subquery in general?

Or do I just have to trick me around such things?

Notice: subqueries in the FROM clause are also forbidden, for all views, so that's also not an option.

**Clarification**:

I am looking for a way to get a view with the same results like

```
CREATE VIEW viewName
AS
SELECT a.someColumn, 
  EXIST( SELECT a FROM table2 t WHERE t2.date > NOW()) AS flag, 
  (SELECT id FROM table3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS latest_id
 FROM table1
```

that uses the merge algorithm.

Comment: I understand the limitations of MySQL views.  I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why do you need the `merge` algorithm?  (By the way:  you may need to use a stored procedure to accomplish what you really want.  MySQL views are notoriously limited compared to other databases.)

Comment: If the view is not using the merge algorithm, mysql creats a giant tempory table (without any index) and runs the actual query on this tempory table. yes i realize this more and more... at the moment i think that there are only a few cases a mysql view is useful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stored function with the `DETERMINISTIC` and `READS SQL DATA` directives that accepts whatever arguments are needed to perform the subquery.  Do the subquery inside the function, and return the result.

Then reference the function inside the view.

Counter-intuitive though it may seem, this abstraction allows the view to be declared with `ALGORITHM=MERGE`, and processed accordingly, so you don't have the performance issues assocated with `TEMPTABLE`.

Comment: oh this is possible? I will try it. I noticed that I dont know how to check, if mysql really uses the merge algorithm. you can specify it, but if mysql thinks it can not use it on the specific view it changes the algorithm to undefined silently without telling about...

Comment: Not quite silently.  It actually throws a warning when it coerces the algorithm back to `UNDEFINED` but whatever client you're using may not be showing you those warnings.  You can check manually, after defining a view, by issuing the query `SHOW WARNINGS;`.